# Are Tasks associated with a Lead carried over to the new Opportunity on conversion?

Tags: opportunity, salesforce-id, tasks, lead-conversion

As I understand it, when a Lead is converted using the standard Salesforce Process, three new Objects are created: a Contact, an Account, and an Opportunity, while the Lead is marked read-only and cannot be subsequently modified.

Do Tasks (and other Objects) associated with the converted Lead then become associated with the new Opportunity, or do they remain associated with the converted Lead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long answer : https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_leads_what_happens_when.htm

Short answer: All open and closed activities from the leads are attached to the accounts, contacts, and opportunities.

As far as custom objects, you may have to write a trigger to associate them to other objects as needed.

Also vote for this idea : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrltAAC

Comment: Ok great, so it looks like standard SF Objects are re-associated, and custom objects should be taken care of by triggers. Got it. Thanks Rao. Also upvoted that idea, I think it would go a long way to resolve some headaches.